# Can I supply a BLDC motor controller with pulses? Or does it necessarily have to be DC?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I'm using a 48v 1500w BLDC motor. Can I run the motor controller using pulses obtained from an ultracapacitor? I talked to a person who said that you can't as he tried it and he blew up his motor controller.  Something along the lines of the motor controller using pwm to run the motor and if we supply it with pulses it'll induce oscillations and make the system unstable.

Comment: Supply a data sheet link for the controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is how e-bikes operate with PWM

Essentially a 1500W SMPS with a pot throttle to control Vref for PWM inside controller and fully protected two-way full-bridge or twin half bridge for braking and  battery charging like in Prius,Tesla etc.

This assumes you know all the design characteristics of the motor losses and dynamic driver losses, torque, SRF, motor impedance", heat mass , inertia for Back EMF and are *an expert in controlled SMPS motive power design.*

Not any Amazon cheapo 30A PWM board will work. ;) but what the heck, buy one anyways for learning curve and get a big CPU heatsink

Surge current from full acceleration will be up to ~8x max average of 30A= 240A based on motor 52V/DCR.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I run the motor controller using pulses obtained from an
>   ultracapacitor?

No. Supplying it with pulses is equivalent to turning the power on and off with every pulse. The controller will then try to start and stop the motor every time, causing high surge currents that could eventually blow it up.

However you *could* (with an appropriate circuit) use the pulses from an ultracapacitor to charge up a battery, which then supplies a constant voltage to the controller.